# I cant do anything but mine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was on version 1.2.2 just for the fun of it, and I went on the settings and changed button 2 by accident and now I can't change it back. I'v tried going on a different version, deleting the world etc. I'd really need help, I'd appreciate it if you will help me. One tip I'm not aloud to delete my mine-craft.

Comment: When you say you're not allowed to delete minecraft... what do you mean? Do you have access to the `%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\` folder? (assuming you're playing on Windows)

Comment: can't change back? press escape go to options, controls and click on the relevant button and then press button 2.

Answer (score 4):

In the `.minecraft` folder, in Windows located by default in your Application Data folder (accessible with the `%APPDATA%` environment variable), there is a file called `options.txt` which contains the key controls.

The default values for the relevant options are:

```
key_key.attack:-100
key_key.use:-99
key_key.forward:17
key_key.left:30
key_key.back:31
key_key.right:32
key_key.jump:57
key_key.sneak:42
key_key.drop:16
key_key.inventory:18
key_key.chat:20
key_key.playerlist:15
key_key.pickItem:-98
key_key.command:53
```

You can edit this file by hand if you are unable to make the changes in the options menu of the game.